# R: How to use IF correctly?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have two columns of values like this:

```
>bb
          GDis      BDis         
    1   12.291488  8.009909  
    2   11.283319 13.625103 
    3   6.674549  8.629232 
    4   13.493121 17.175888 
    5   9.550731  9.867878 
    6   9.193895  9.785301 
    7   10.541702 10.941371 
    8   9.849527  9.496284  
    9   8.682287  8.133774  
    10  8.439381  4.335260
```

I need to add extra column and call it `Index` which calculates ratio `GDis/BDis` if `GDis` is bigger, and `BDis/GDis` if `BDis` is bigger.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 transform(bb, Index=ifelse(GDis>BDis, GDis/BDis, BDis/GDis))
 #        GDis      BDis      adn
 #1  12.291488  8.009909 1.534535
 #2  11.283319 13.625103 1.207544
 #3   6.674549  8.629232 1.292856
 #4  13.493121 17.175888 1.272937
 #5   9.550731  9.867878 1.033207
 #6   9.193895  9.785301 1.064326
 #7  10.541702 10.941371 1.037913
 #8   9.849527  9.496284 1.037198
 #9   8.682287  8.133774 1.067436
 #10  8.439381  4.335260 1.946684
```

Comment: Ah, thats easy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pmax` and `pmin`.

```
transform(bb, Index = pmax(GDis, BDis) / pmin(GDis, BDis))
```

You can also use arithmetics:

```
transform(bb, Index = (GDis / BDis) ^ (1 - 2 * (BDis > GDis)))
```

The result:

```
        GDis      BDis    Index
1  12.291488  8.009909 1.534535
2  11.283319 13.625103 1.207544
3   6.674549  8.629232 1.292856
4  13.493121 17.175888 1.272937
5   9.550731  9.867878 1.033207
6   9.193895  9.785301 1.064326
7  10.541702 10.941371 1.037913
8   9.849527  9.496284 1.037198
9   8.682287  8.133774 1.067436
10  8.439381  4.335260 1.946684
```

Comment: This one works perfectly as well! thank you! Very appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Not as nice as the other answers but how about this?

```
bb$RATIO=ifelse(bb$GDis>bb$BDis,bb$GDis/bb$BDis,bb$X1/bb$GDis)
```